# Find the winner of each stage

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am learning SQL, and I am trying to get a job. I have the following table in MS SQL Server 2014:

The table is called Game with the following fields: Name, Stage #, Score.

My goal is to write the winner of each stage with his/her name (winner of the stage is the person who earned the maximum score).

Here is the original table:

```
Name    Stage #         Score
George     A              10
Joe        A              10
Pete       A               9
Jane       B               7
Sally      B               6
```

Here is what the output should look like:

```
Winner Name    Score         Stage
George           10             A
Joe              10             A
Jane              7             B
```

How can I accomplish this task? A colleague referred me to http://sqlfiddle.com/ to help me figure this out, but this website is apparently not working well for MS SQL Server 2014 or MS SQL Server 2008. Therefore, can I receive some assistance here?

I understand some of the basic functions, such as SELECT, WHERE, GROUP BY, JOIN, and HAVING, but I am having trouble putting it all together to get the correct three-line output that I desire above.

Comment: "A colleague referred me to http://sqlfiddle.com/ to help me figure this out…" – you mean you don't have access to an instance of SQL Server to be able to work out a solution (whether at home or at work/school)? Does that mean that you won't be able to *test* whatever solution you will be offered here?

Answer (score 11):

There are tens of different ways to do this in SQL. Lets start with the simple correlated subquery (mind the fancy name, once you see and write a few of them, they are very easy to understand):

```
select                                -- show
    g.name, g.stage, g.score          -- all data
from                                  -- from
    game as g                         -- the table
where                                 -- where
    not exists                        -- there isn't
        ( select *                    -- any other 
          from game as g2             -- from the same table
          where g2.stage = g.stage    -- and the same stage
            and g2.score > g.score    -- with bigger score
        ) ;
```

Another simple way would be to first find the biggest score for each stage using `GROUP BY` (in a subquery, either a derived table or a CTE) and then `JOIN` back to the original table:

```
-- using derived table
select      
    g.name, g.stage, g.score 
from      
    game as g 
  join
    ( select stage, max(score) as score
      from game
      group by stage
    ) as m
  on  m.stage = g.stage
  and m.score = g.score ;

-- using CTE
with stage_max as
    ( select stage, max(score) as score
      from game
      group by stage
    ) 
select      
    g.name, g.stage, g.score 
from      
    game as g 
  join
    stage_max as m
  on  m.stage = g.stage
  and m.score = g.score ;
```

A more modern way would be to use window functions (available in your SQL Server versions), i.e. the `RANK()` function, so first you get the "rank" of everyone per stage and then select only the ones with `rank=1`. This can also be done with either a derived table or a CTE:

```
-- window functions, using derived table
select      
    w.name, w.stage, w.score 
from      
    ( select name, stage, score,
             rnk = rank() over (partition by stage
                                order by score desc)
      from game
    ) as w
where
    w.rnk = 1 ;

-- window functions, using CTE
with ranking as
    ( select name, stage, score,
             rnk = rank() over (partition by stage
                                order by score desc)
      from game
    ) 
select      
    w.name, w.stage, w.score 
from      
    ranking as w 
where
    w.rnk = 1 ;
```

Answer (score 4):

Another solution, that some people find most intuitive (and others don't):

```
SELECT
    [Winner Name] = G.name,              -- The result columns
    G.score,
    Stage = G.stage#
FROM dbo.game AS G
WHERE
    G.score =                            -- For rows where the score equals
    (
        SELECT
            MAX(G2.score)                -- The highest score
        FROM dbo.game AS G2
        WHERE
            G2.stage# = G.stage#         -- Within the same stage
    )
ORDER BY
    G.stage# DESC,
    G.score DESC;
```

Despite the two references to the table, this typically only accesses the table once:

[image: Execution plan]

Remember, SQL is a declarative language: You use it to specify the *results* you want, not *how to get them*.

A suitable index would remove the need for the Sort above.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to the site. Instead of ascii tables with data it is better to provide create table statements and insert statements like:

```
create table game 
(    name varchar(20) not null
,    stage# char(1) not null
,    score int not null
,        primary key (name, stage#) -- assumed this one
);

insert into game (name, stage#,score) 
values ('George','A',10)
     , ('Joe','A',10)
     , ('Pete','A',9)
     , ('Jane','B',7)
     , ('Sally','B',6);
```

This way it becomes much easier for others to reproduce your scenario.

As @YperSillyCubeᵀᴹ points out there are a lot of ways you can solve this problem. Here's one example that illustrates using a join against a derived table:

```
select a.name as winner_name, a.score, a.stage# 
from game as a 
join ( 
    select stage#, max(score) as max_score 
    from game 
    group by stage# 
) as b 
    on a.stage# = b.stage# 
   and a.score = b.max_score;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution, hope this will help you.

Given Sample:

```
Name    Stage #         Score
George     A              10
Joe        A              10
Pete       A               9
Jane       B               7
Sally      B               6
```

Required Condition:

```
Winner Name    Score         Stage
George           10             A
Joe              10             A
Jane              7             B
```

Solution:

```
DECLARE @Temp TABLE 
(
    Name  VARCHAR(250),
    Stage VARCHAR(10),
    Score INT 
);

INSERT INTO @Temp
    ( Name, Stage, Score )
VALUES  
    ('George',     'A',              10),
    ('Joe',       'A',              10),
    ('Pete',       'A',               9),
    ('Jane',       'B',               7),
    ('Sally',      'B',               6)

SELECT * FROM @Temp

SELECT 
    b.name,Stage, Score 
FROM
    (
        SELECT Stage, MAX(Score) AS Score 
        FROM @Temp 
        GROUP BY Stage
    ) a
CROSS APPLY 
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT name 
        FROM @Temp [_a] 
        WHERE [_a].Score = a.Score 
        AND [_a].Stage = a.Stage
    ) b
ORDER BY 
    a.Stage,b.Name
```